# SLURM job script to rsync files

Tags: rsync, file-transfer, slurm

Is there a way to submit a SLURM script to transfer files?

I use *rsync* with command bar but I don't know how to do something similar with a SLURM script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=transfer             # Job name
#SBATCH --mail-type=END,FAIL                   # Mail events (NONE, BEGIN, END, FAIL, ALL)
#SBATCH --mail-user=tdhasdhj@hbdahi.com
#SBATCH --ntasks=3          # Run N tasks
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1   # Number of CPU cores per task
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu= 10000# Memory per thread
#SBATCH --time= 100:00:00     # Time limit hrs:min:sec

What command here?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command will simply be whatever rsync command you want to run, i.e. `rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]`

You probably don't want `--ntasks=3` unless you're using `xargs` or `parallel` to use multiple CPUs